# How to move line up and down in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't know if something has changed recently in Visual Studio 2015 but before I was able to press `ALT + UP ARROW KEY` or `ALT + DOWN ARROW KEY` to move lines in code up or down and now it does not do anything.

I went into `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard` and I cannot find anything like in the past called
`ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Item.MoveUp`
or
`ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Item.MoveDown`

Also here in the list of VS2015 I don't see that option:
http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The commands you are looking for are **Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp** and **Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown**. Shortcuts for them should be defined in the **Text Editor** context.

Comment: Thanks Sergey! It works well, I think ReSharper must have messed up my shortcuts or something.

Answer (score 0):

SuperUser answer: https://superuser.com/questions/479486/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-line-up-down-in-visual-studio-2012/481015#481015

- Alt-ArrowUp
- Alt-ArrowDown